# Assets can't be found in LibGDX project

Tags: java, parsing, libgdx, assets, tiled

**Issue:** I've created a game map with Tiled and imported it into the core assets directory of a LibGDX project. The assets, however, can't be found while running the application.

**Error:** com.badlogix.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:File not found: Sprites/Tilesets/PixelFantasy_Caves_1.0/background1.png (internal)

[image: run configurations]

The map gets loaded in this class:

```
public class PlayView implements Screen {

    private Sirius game;
    private OrthographicCamera spielCam;
    private Viewport spielPort;
    private Hud hud;

    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;

    public PlayView(Sirius game) {
        this.game = game;
        spielCam = new OrthographicCamera();
        spielPort = new FitViewport(Sirius.V_WIDTH, Sirius.V_HEIGHT, spielCam);
        hud = new Hud(game.batch);

        mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        map = mapLoader.load("siriusMap.tmx");
        renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        spielCam.position.set(spielPort.getWorldWidth() / 2, spielPort.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. If the Tiled project gets created inside the core/assets directory of the libGDX project, the error doesn't occure.